# How do you do obtain the sum $244 + 132$ in base $5$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Express the following sum in base $5$ notation:

$$244_{5} + 132_{5} $$

where $244_{5}$ means $2 \cdot 5^{2} + 4 \cdot 5^{1} + 4 \cdot 5^{0}$ (i.e., $244$ is already in base $5$ notation).

**My attempt:**
$244 \cdot 5^1 + 132 \cdot 5^0$

Is that correct? Because this is the first time I hear of (Base 5 notation).
Thanks in advance,
here the exact question 
Perform the following arithmetic operations for the numbers in the bases indicated and write out answers in base 5 notation:
a)  244 + 132 (base 5).
b)  11101 × 111 (base 2). 
c)  F7 – B6 (base 16).

Comment: No, it is not correct.  Have you ever heard of "base 10"?  To add 244+ 132 in base 10, you would **not** say "244(10^1)+ 132(10^2)!  "244 base 5" is the same as 2(5^2)+ 4(5)+ 4(1) and "132 base 5" is 1(25)+ 3(5)+ 3.  So "244 base 5" is 40+ 20+ 4= 64 in base 10 and "122 base 5" is 25+ 15+ 3= 43 in base 10.  64+ 43= 107. in base 10.  Going back to base 5, 107= 100+ 5+ 2= 4(25)+ 5+ 2= 452 in base 5.

Comment: Do you mean $244$ and $132$ are given in base $5$? Or rather they are in decimal and you need to express the sum in base $5$?

Comment: Yes they are given in base 5

Comment: @SaedQ.Yousef You should have said that from the beginning, because my answer relied on the idea that they were given in base $10$.  And I got 2 downvotes as a result. :( :( :(

Comment: Dang!  I keep forgetting "carriage return" kicks me out!  I wanted to include that you **can** add directly: Starting on the right, 4+ 2= 6 which is larger than 5: 6= 5+ 1= 11 in base 5 so we "bring down a 1 and carry 1".  Then the next column becomes 1+ 4+ 3= 8= 5+ 3= 13 in base 5 so we "bring down 3 and carry 1.  The final column is 1+ 2+ 1= 4.  We get 431 (base 5).

Comment: Okay, let me explain what I did below. Just add digit by digit. You get 376. And if the lowest digit (6) is greater than 5, then subtract 5 from it but instead add 1 to the next digit. You now get 381. As 8 is greater than 5, subtract 5 from it but add 1 to the next digit. You get 431. Done.

Comment: In this *specific* case I’d do it by noting that $244=300-1$, so $$244+132=300+132-1=300+131=431\;.$$

Comment: The answer you awarded shows you how to convert the sum into base $10$.  Bernard and CiaPan have demonstrated how to find the sum $244_5 + 132_5$ in base $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the numbers are given in base $5$, that is they are $244_5$ and $132_5$, adding goes similar to adding in decimal, except the 'carry' takes place when the result exceeds $4$, not $9$:

```
    244
  + 132
  _____
     11  4+2 = (4+1)+1 = 10(carry) + 1
    12   4+3 = (4+1)+2 = 10(carry) + 2
  + 3    2+1 = 3  does not exceed 4, no carry
  _____
    431
```

$$244_5 + 132_5 = 431_5$$

Answer (score 3):

Here how you do this addition in base $5$, which goes exactly as in base $10$: each time the sum of a series of digits is greater than $5$ you write down the remainder of these digits modulo $5$, and carry the quotient to the next series of digits (from right to left):

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
^{\color{red}1}2&^{\color{red}1}4&4\\1&3&2\\\hline
4&3&1
\end{array}$$
This is because $\;4+2=\color{red}1\cdot 5+1$ and  $\;1+4+3=\color{red}1\cdot 5+3$

Let's check: $\;(244)_5=2\cdot 5^2+4\cdot5+4=(74)_{10}$, $\quad (132)_5=1\cdot 5^2+3\cdot5+2=(42)_{10}$, and
$(431)_5=4\cdot 5^2+3\cdot5+1=(116)_{10}=(74)_{10}+(42)_{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer was:
$$244_{(5)}+132_{(5)}=376_{(5)}=381_{(5)}=431_{(5)}$$
Tomi edited (thanks!):
$$(2 \times 5^2 + 4 \times 5^1 + 4 \times 5^0)+(1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 5^1 + 2 \times 5^0)=3 \times 5^2 + 7 \times 5^1 + 6 \times 5^0$$ $$ = 3 \times 5^2 + (7+1) \times 5^1 + (6-5) \times 5^0= 3 \times 5^2 + 8 \times 5^1 + 1 \times 5^0$$ $$= (3+1) \times 5^2 + (8-5) \times 5^1 + 1 \times 5^0= 4 \times 5^2 + 3\times 5^1 + 1 \times 5^0$$

Comment: Can you explain what did you do please ?

Comment: At least the result is correct (the only one on the page, so far).

Comment: It's like doing 93+28 in decimal. 93+28={11}{11}={11+1}{11-10}={12}{1}={1}{2}{1}=121

Comment: 244+132={3}{7}{6}={3}{7+1}{6-5}={3}{8}{1}={3+1}{8-5}{1}=431

Comment: The result is correct, but the notation is fallacious, as digits $6$, $7$ and $8$ do **not exist** in the base-$5$ system. You should not write decimal digits inside base-$5$ numbers.

Comment: @CiaPan Well, complex numbers do not exist in real world, But if we use them then it makes calculations much easier. I guess you never use complex numbers as they don't exist. :-)

Comment: @CiaPan "Fallacious" is too strong. I was not aware of the approach using such intermediary steps when I discovered this answer but, after having thought about it, I fail to see what could go wrong using them. Maybe you could be more specific about it?

Comment: @Did Thanks. Somebody edited my answer to fix the "fallacious". I appreciate but I like my original answer too. As discussion keeps going i also recovered it as a reference.

Comment: @CiaPan: Did is correct. In fact, this is essentially how carrying in addition base ten is often explained when it is first introduced in elementary school, though in that context pictorial representations of numbers as collections of objects often replace digits.

Answer (score 0):

What [base](http://betterexplained.com/articles/numbers-and-bases/) means is when you move over one space you move up one power of the base. So 132 in base 5 means 1 group of $5^2=25$, 3 groups of $5^1=5$ and 2 groups of $5^0=1$. So if you would like to convert that to base 10 (the numbers you usually think of) it would be $1\cdot25 + 3\cdot5 + 2\cdot1$. Likewise you can do the same with 244 giving you $2\cdot25 + 4\cdot5 + 4\cdot1$. If you add these numbers up you get your answer but in base 10 rather than base 5.

$$1\cdot25 + 3\cdot5 + 2\cdot1 + 2\cdot25 + 4\cdot5 + 4\cdot1 = 116$$

To finish your problem you then need to convert back to base 5. (As a note $5^3=125$). To convert back what you want to do it look for the number of groups of the highest power. If you answer base 10 is greater than 125 subtract from it the largest number of groups of 125 that you can, then move on to the next smallest power of 5. The number of groups you subtract away will be your answer.

$$116-4*25=16$$
$$16-3*5=1$$

So the final answer is 431.

Answer (score 0):

Each has value of 5 powers from $0$. starting from least important bit to most significant bit[LSB-MSB]. So $132+244=376$ so in base 5 its $5^0.6+5^1.7+5^2.3=6+35+75=116_{10}$

Comment: This is converting the decimal sum of decimal terms into base $5$, but it turned out that the numbers given were in base $5$, not decimal: $132_5 = 42$ and $244_5 = 74$ give $116 = 431_5$.

Comment: Please fix your answer, $6+35+75=116$ but **not** $116_5$.